# Create a restful api endpoint so that I can connect my angular 8 app to it

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, api, express

I am new to angular and node.js and would like to know how I could approach the following problem. So, I am using an angular 8 application for my front-end and I am trying to connect it to a node.js application which is my backend. The github to the node application can be found here (https://github.com/pepzwee/node-csgo-web-tradebot). The node application has an index.js file for the routing, index.html file to display the content and an app.js file (located in: static/js/app.js) for the logic. Now, I want to be able to get rid of the index.html so that I can use my angular app for it and connect the endpoints by using the ff:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    //give access endpoint to angular app by accessing json format
})
```

That way I can get a json file of available methods and variables which I can use in my angular app to build out my UI once I go to the domain of the node app. I know that most of the logic is in the app.js file but it is not in a json format. I have no clue how to edit the app.js file to make it json and eventually connect it to the index.js file, in order to be able to access it via angular app.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you could post the app.js that would help to get an understanding of exactly how your app is set up. I am not totally sure what you mean by making app.js a JSON? But here is a rough idea of connecting the two.

**Node Side app.js:**

To link your index.js to your app you can do the following in app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const indexFile = require('<relative-path-to-index-file>');

router.use('/indexFile', indexFile); // this would give you the endpoint localhost:3000/indexFile
```

Then in index.js the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/get', (req, res) => {

})

router.post('/post', (req, res) => {
    // to access body from angular use req.body
    // to send data back use req.send() or req.json() for JSON object
})

module.exports = router;
```

This will allow you to have a separate file with your endpoints in it.

**Angular Side:**

On Angular I would create a service. You can create a file `name.service.ts` and use the following general code.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class NameService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  serviceMethodPost(body) {
    return this.http.post('localhost:3000/indexFile/post', body);
  }

  serviceMethodGet() {
    return this.http.get('localhost:3000/indexFile/get');
  }
}
```

Then in whatever controller you would like to make the request from use:

```
constructor(private nameService: NameService) { } // make sure to import at the top

...

this.nameService.serviceMethodPost(body).subscribe(returnedValue => {
    // do any logic you would like with the returned value or when request complete          
});

this.nameService.serviceMethodGet().subscribe(returnedValue => {
    // do any logic you would like with the returned value or when request complete          
});
```

Hopefully, this gave you a good start on connecting your Node and Angular apps.